# cakephpのtagsプラグインを使用しているのですが配列の取り出しかたがわかりません。

Tags: php, cakephp

お世話になっております。
`<?php echo $uploads["Upload"]["tags"]; ?>`とすると
`php, html, cakephp`
のように,(カンマ)がついて表示されますが、
`php html cakephp` の一つ一つを表示させて、タグの一つ一つを分けてデザインがつくようにしたいです。
`<?php echo $uploads["Upload"]["Tagged"]["name"]; ?>`
としても個別で表示されないのですが、どうしたら個別でタグを表示させることができるでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
array(4) { 
["Upload"]=> array(18) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "7" 
    ["name"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["subject"]=> string(15) "文字列表示" 
    ["body"]=> string(36) "PHPで文字列を表示させる。" 
    ["tags"]=> string(18) "php, html, cakephp"
} 

["Tag"]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(8) { 
        ["id"]=> string(36) "558fee8a-01c4-4cad-9d54-23caac1f12c5" 
        ["identifier"]=> NULL 
        ["name"]=> string(3) "php" 
        ["keyname"]=> string(3) "php" 
        ["weight"]=> string(1) "0" 

        ["Tagged"]=> array(8) {

    [1]=> array(8) { 
        ["id"]=> string(36) "558fee8a-dddc-407b-af90-23caac1f12c5" 
        ["identifier"]=> NULL 
        ["name"]=> string(4) "html" 
        ["keyname"]=> string(4) "html" 
        ["weight"]=> string(1) "0" 

        ["Tagged"]=> array(8) { 
             ["id"]=> string(36) "5595e50c-0e04-4177-9de8-79eaac1f12c5" 
             ["foreign_key"]=> string(1) "7" 
             ["tag_id"]=> string(36) "558fee8a-dddc-407b-af90-23caac1f12c5" 
             ["model"]=> string(6) "Upload"
             ["language"]=> string(2) "ja" 
             ["times_tagged"]=> string(1) "1" 

    [2]=> array(8) { 
        ["id"]=> string(36) "55922ed8-757c-4dc4-b50b-79edac1f12c5" 
        ["identifier"]=> NULL 
        ["name"]=> string(7) "cakephp" 
        ["keyname"]=> string(7) "cakephp" 
        ["weight"]=> string(1) "0" 

        ["Tagged"]=> array(8) { 
            ["id"]=> string(36) "5595e50c-8180-4c4a-80a2-79eaac1f12c5" 
            ["foreign_key"]=> string(1) "7" 
            ["tag_id"]=> string(36) "55922ed8-757c-4dc4-b50b-79edac1f12c5" 
            ["model"]=> string(6) "Upload" 
            ["language"]=> string(2) "ja" 
            ["times_tagged"]=> string(1) "1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$uploads["Upload"]["Tagged"]` が配列になっているようですから、それを foreach で順番に取り出し、その中の `["name"]` を表示してはいかがでしょうか。

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($uploads["Upload"]["Tagged"] as $tag): ?>
    <li><?php echo $tag["name"]; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

ここでは `foreach(...):` `endforeach;` という書き方を使いましたが、まとまったPHPコードであれば以下のような記法も一般的です。

```
<?php

foreach (...) {
  echo "hoge";
}
```

[PHP: foreach - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ja/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: ビューファイル（.ctp）で制御構造を書くときは、可読性確保のため `foreach(...):` `endforeach;`や`if (...):` `endif;` のようにキーワードでの制御構造にすべきです。`{}`だと、どの`{`と`}`が対応しているのかわかりにくくなります。（余談失礼